# Open but not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In general there is no relation between the conditions of openness and continuity for functions between topological spaces.

For example, $f\colon (\mathbb{R}, \text{left ray topology})\to (\mathbb{R}, \text{discrete topology})$  given by $f(x)=x$ is open but not continuous.

My question if there is a function $(\mathbb{R}, \text{usual topology})\to  (\mathbb{R}, \text{usual topology})$ which is open but not continuous?

And if so, what the conditions must be in this function to be open and not continuous?

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62395.html

Comment: Is there another example?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I edited the question for formatting and grammar. I left your last sentence as is, because I have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 4):

The [Conway base 13 function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a rather extreme example: it is nowhere continuous but $f[(a,b)] = \mathbb{R}$ for all $a < b$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and this trivially implies that $f$ is open.

Comment: Beautiful example of the crazyness of real functions.